# Create Phonegap app with "kiosk mode"

Tags: java, android, cordova, kiosk

I am trying to create Phonegap app that runs in a "kiosk mode" that won't allow the user to either leave or close the app, have acces to the notification bar or use anything else than the app we created.

The idea is that we incorporate a tablet (samsung galaxy tab 4 10.1) in an endcap which will then be placed in certain stores. Whether or tot the physical buttons on the tablet will accessible to the user has not be defined yet.

I do have experience with Phonegap but i have no idea on how to accomplish this.
So far i have tried several guides and resources, i.e. this one: http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/ or solutions as SureLock but without succes.

The tablet we want to use: samsung galaxy tab 4 10.1 (SM-T533)
Android version: 4.4.4
Phonegap version: 5.1.1

Answer (score 1):

> Cordova Kiosk Mode - Cordova plugin to create Cordova application with
>   "kiosk mode". App with this plugin can be set as Android launcher. If
>   app starts as launcher, it blocks hardware buttons and statusbar, so
>   the user cannot close the app until the app request it.

https://github.com/honza889/cordova-plugin-kiosk

Answer (score 0):

Kiosk mode is highly platform specific. I'd recommend building a native app instead of using phonegap.

If you absolutely want to use phonegap you'd have to implement these hacks inside a plugin (which is in fact native code, so you don't gain anything).

Comment: To be perfectly honest, using Phonegap just makes it easier for me to develop an app. Although i have nothing against developing natively, java just issn't my forte as of now.

Comment: My point is: the Webview Sandbox is too limited to implement this. Phonegap gives you the possibility to escape this sandbox - but only with the help of native code. If you're really lucky someone has already published a plugin for this, but I doubt it.

Comment: I know and that is exactly my intention. It won't be possible without native code. It is just that i have no idea on how to do it since i know to little of java.

Comment: You should probably first learn how to use a framework before you start exploiting it... The tutorial you linked is very straightforward and almost can't be explained better.

Comment: Above the "hello world" Level,  here are some tutorials which might help you in the specific case of your linked hacks https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Comment: Awesome, i will definitely have a look at it!